# access and modify data related SVG element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I access/modify an data related SVG element in place? I got an interval function, which executes every 3 seconds to control the data.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if(data[i].active) {
             //THIS SVG node.. .style("fill", "green")
          } else {
             //THIS SVG node.. .style("fill", "red")
          }
      }
}, 3000)
```

Or do I need to re-initialize the whole D3.js graph each time?

Comment: For me, the usual practice is to update the whole D3 compound with enter/merge/exit pattern, but what you want to do will also work... I also think you don't need to iterate every node if you have an only `active` one. You just reset the previously active and then set the new active using class selector